# AWS lambda to fetch data from tables and send report to the distribution list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

We are working on ETL project to transfer on-prem data to AWS.
We have SNS to trigger Step-function and further glue jobs for the process.
I need to create a lambda function, that is triggered by that sns, get details from audit table and create a report and send to the distribution list.

Question 1: Is it possible to create any kind of pdf report and send it to the distribution list via the same SNS ?
Question 2: I know that the sns alert message size is 256 kb, now I have long list of 400 tables, not sure how to calculate the size of the email msg in case I just want to publish alert email with tabular text

Comment: Believe you'd have to use SES for larger email content. Why send the report by email anyway? Do you have other options? Perhaps you could make it available via a web page, and simply use SNS to send the link to that web page. Bonus: it would always be up to date.

Comment: we want to use the existing SNS (used to trigger step function) to trigger the lambda as the same sns contains batch information and that batch information is required in the sql to fetch the details from the aurora database. We can't use SES as we don't want to introduce a new service in the design. This report is basically to let us know the table counts loaded. Nothing fancy

Comment: If you must send a PDF by email via SNS, then I think you'll need to find a more compact way to represent the info that fits into 256 KB. Or simply send an email containing a (secured) link to the content.

Comment: I think better would be to just get the rows/columns from table and dump it into sns and send to the distribution list. How can I make sure the size of content ? is there any way to try that ?

Comment: @jarmod - we are not storing the report anywhere, do we need to host the report at S3 and then provide the link ? and we need to add code to add html content in lambda, is that correct thinking?

Comment: I can't tell you what you need to do, these are your decisions. I'm proposing that you think differently about solving this problem i.e. don't send a too-large PDF but find some other way to share the salient info (reduce the size of the PDF, or ZIP it, or just send simple text email instead with the pertinent information, or host the PDF somewhere secure and share a link to it, etc.)

Comment: For now, I will try sending the retrieved data in sns text email. I want to run a query and put all the retrieved rows/columns in the table structure in email and send. Do you think cursor.fetchall() will work or need more code to support that?

Comment: is there a way to use aws lambda, retrieve the tabular data, create a report in text or pdf format and send it via email and also upload to s3

Comment: If you can code it, then you can almost certainly run it in Lambda. Yes, you can make SNS and S3 API calls from Lambda, of course. You can call APIs etc.

Comment: Now I am thinking to let lambda read tables, dump data in a csv file and upload it to s3. I will explore if that file can be attached with SNS or SES via email because we can't provide s3 access to the consumers